# How to bridge Objective-C in Xcode 7 beta 6 (7A192o) using swift 2.0?

Tags: objective-c, swift2, xcode7

I am trying to create a bridge header file in order to use certain objective c libraries. But I did not find the Objective-C Bridging Header option in the build settings in Xcode 7. [image]

[image]

Comment: Where are the libraries coming from? Are they modules? If so then you don't need a bridging header.

Comment: I am trying to use remoteimageview library , MBProgressHUD library, etc..

Comment: Via CocoaPods, Carthage or some other package manager?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your screenshot, instead of selecting "Basic", Select "All ", you should be able to see the Objective-C Bridging Header Setting. You can then set your_header_file.h as value. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

"Objective-C Bridging Header" is under "Swift Compiler - Code Generation".  Go to targets > Build Settings > and/or do a search for  "Swift Compiler - Code Generation"

Comment: I cant find the objective -c bridging header option there, Please see the snapshot that I have updated

Comment: This may be obvious, but I'm assuming you already added the bridging file to your project?